# lottieanimationview is not fabric compatible yet

Tags: react-native, lottie

dispatchcommand called without surfacedId fabric dispatcommand must be called through fabric JSI API

with `react-native 0.70.3` and `new-architecture` enabled.

```
{
  npm: '8.19.2',
  node: '14.17.6',
  v8: '8.4.371.23-node.76',
  uv: '1.41.0',
  zlib: '1.2.11',
  brotli: '1.0.9',
  ares: '1.17.2',
  modules: '83',
  nghttp2: '1.42.0',
  napi: '8',
  llhttp: '2.1.3',
  openssl: '1.1.1l',
  cldr: '39.0',
  icu: '69.1',
  tz: '2021a',
  unicode: '13.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the new architecture support, like described in their official doc by running:

```
yarn add lottie-react-native@next
```

this command will install lottie-react-native package from the next channel wich may resolve the issue,another alternative ( if you really want to use lottie animation library ) is to disable the new architecture ( android/gradle.properties ) and set the newArchEnabled to false value =>   newArchEnabled=false
NB: also dont forget to install lottie-ios@3.4.1 in case you want to use the new architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with `react-native 0.72.5` and after update to the last version of `lottie-react-native`, wich is  `lottie-react-native@6.4.1` at this moment, everything runned smothly.